# What does 'int' signify when used in xml configurations in spring integration?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

I am currently reading through spring integration topics. Came across a notation/prefix --> "int" used in the XML configurations in spring-integration.

```
<int:channel id="errorChannel">
<int:queue capacity="500"/>
```

Can anyone help me in understanding it ? Also somewhere I have seen 'si' being used. What exactly these prefixes specify & are they spring integration specific ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

See the top of the file:

```
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
```

The prefix is mapped to an xml namespace (xmlns). Further down...

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd"
```

The namespace maps to the schema location, which Spring finds in the jar via `/META-INF/spring.schemas`. The schema defines the elements and what properties they have.

The prefix can be whatever you want, `int`, `si`, `integration`, `foo`.

It's just a mapping.